# is there a parameter to inhibit IFilter feature on windows 7 search?

Tags: windows-7, pdf, search, windows-search

This question originates after [this one](https://superuser.com/questions/930417/how-can-i-change-a-windows-search-indexing-options-when-i-get-the-you-do-not-ha).
The two questions are independent even if they share a common problem basis so I'm asking this now hoping somebody can help me with at least one of the two.
*COMMON BASIS: After installing IFilter it seems like searching for file names (NOT USING "contents:" parameter in search query to check even file contents) PDF files are always the same searched even in their contents resulting in list of files including PDF ones whose names aren't containing the word(s) I'm looking for.*

So the question is: **is there a parameter to use within the windows search query to force IFilter turn off?**

I already looked [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa965711%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [here](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/advanced-tips-for-searching-in-windows) not finding something of use for this... I'm loosing hope.
I'd really appreciate your help with this or with the previous question, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Searching for file names (NOT USING "contents") [filename only search]:

Press <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> and run:

```
search-ms:query=((ext:.pdf)LIKE(-filename:"*filename*"))
```

- change `"*filename*"` to your query - part of filename

List of ALL files (PDF included) in a folder whose name contains "test" NOT searching inside file contents:

Windows 7:

```
search-ms:query=folder:*test*
```

or

```
search-ms:query=foldername:*test*
```

You do not work with IFilter during the search.

You are working with requests to the index sql server. IFilter working briefly for incremental indexing. IFilter working at reindex if there are files of its type.

If you want to do without the saved in sql - a simple search on the file system command `dir`.

Or if difficult conditions - the powershell.

If you need INSTANT search - Working with indexes sql.

Or with a normal third-party software that works with tables MFT, which we have not seen.

NTFS also allows you to work with their accounts much more efficient, but this functionality is not enough implemented. There are specialists who write drivers for filesystems, but I'm unfortunately not one of them.

Comment: Hi STTR, thank for your answer. How can I use it? Where do I have to write that query? Suppose I'm searching for all files (including PDF) in a folder whose name contains "test". I tried with search-ms:query=((ext:.pdf)LIKE(-filename:"test")) but doesn't seem to work. Thank you.

Comment: press WinKey+R and run query

Comment: Oh yeah, is it the same as writing ((ext:.pdf)LIKE(-filename:"*filename*")) directly on... let me call it the "explorer's folder search-box" (in the upper right corner)? Anyway I think the query is not doing the "trick"... Can you explain what it is supposed to do? (intuitively it looks to me like that it will list all PDF files whose name doesn't contain "filename"... is it?)

Comment: Yes. Search part filename at Windows Index at all location. Change `"*filename*"` to you query

Comment: yes, I did it, replaced `"*filename*"` with `"*test*"` but the results aren't the one I expect. I want a list of ALL files (PDF included) in a folder whose name contains "test" NOT searching inside file contents.

Comment: @danicotra Update.

Comment: Thank you for the update STTR, anyway I didn't expressed well: what I meant was _I want a list of ALL files (PDF included) inside a folder (named "myfolder" or whatever) whose name contains "test" NOT searching inside file contents_. **My real problem here is the IFilter make the search always active on PDF files content even if I don't put `contents:` parameter in my search query. What I need is a way to inhibit this feature... for example with a parameter or something else forcing IFIlter to turn off during the search.**

Comment: If need don't use iFilters use file content search or application API: MS Office, Acrobat and etc. You need alternative file manager or script. See Update too.